# How to connect Speex Decompressor to Audio Mixer in Delphi code (Mitov AudioLab components)

Tags: delphi, audio, mitov-audio-lab

First of all, this is my first question on SO - if I made any mistakes, please do not tar and feather me ;)

I have a simple test application to play with the Mitov AudioLab components (www.mitov.com) version 7 in Delphi XE6. On my form, there is a TALWavePlayer, a TALSpeexCompressor, a TALSpeexDecompressor, a TALAudioMixer and a TALAudioOut, building a simple audio processing chain. I can connect the inputs and outputs visually at design time (in the OpenWire view).  when I run my test application, I can hear the wave file through the speaker - whithout a single line of code. That's the easy (working) part.

(grrrr... can't post images, would have made things much clearer ;)

Now I disconnect the TALSpeexDecompressor output pin from the TALAudioMixer input pin visually at design time (OpenWire view). I want to replace this same connection in code at run time. (For the sake of simplicity I keep the single input pin and channel of the TALAudioMixer, so they do not need to be created in code).

I tried exactly the same optoins that work to connect other AudioLab components at run time (audio output pin -> audio input pin).

1.) `decomp.OutputPin.Connect(mixer.InputPins[0]);`

2.) `decomp.OutputPin.Connect(mixer.Channels.Items[0].InputPin);`

But with the TALSpeexDecompressor, this does not work - there is no signal leaving the decompressor. I do not have the source code of the components, so I cannot debug the application to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: You can post images on sites like ImageShack, then edit your post and put the links in. Someone else will edit your post again and place the actual images in it. I see you already found the answer, but please add the images so that your post is (more) valuable for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Stop and then start the wave player again after connecting the decompressor and the mixer dynamically. This somehow solves the issue. I do not know what happens under the hood, but after restarting the TALWavePlayer, the signal leaves the TALSpeexDecompressor and enters the TALAudioMixer. I stumbled over the solution when I set the "filename" property of the TALWavePlayer component in code, not in the property editor. Because of another (default) setting "RestartOnNewFile" = True, the wave player was restarted internally and the signal flow worked.

```
procedure Tform1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  channel: TALAudioMixerChannelItem;
begin
    channel := mixer.Channels.Add;
    waveplayer.Stop;
    channel.InputPin.Connect(decomp.OutputPin);
    waveplayer.Start;
end;
```

It is obvious that the AudioLab components can make simple tasks even simpler, but due to the poor documentation in their DocuWiki you have to follow the "try and error" path often, sometimes even for days. Unfortunately my real issue is more complicated than the simple test case I provided. I have an UDP client and server in the chain, so I have no control over the wave player on the client side when I dynamically connect the decompressor to the mixer on the server side. Obviously a deeper knowledge of these components is required, perhaps coming from experience. So this will be my next question here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies to everyone for the insufficient documentation in the components :-( .
We are working to get a new release in the next 3-4 weeks that will contain again the F1 help, and we are working to make it as complete as possible.

Unfortunately we had to release the 7.0 without documentation in order to have it available on time for the RAD Studio XE6 :-( .

Please contact me directly - mitov@mitov.com so I can help you with the Speex issue, and connecting the pins.

With best regards,

Boian Mitov